# Illegal characters in path [Visual Basic]

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I created a small program where a file dropped over the EXE triggers action on that file. It works fine as long as the path to the file does not contain spaces.

When there is a folder with spaces in the name, such as \Visual Studio 2013\file (actual path much longer), I get an 'Illegal characters in path'.

Under Unix, I would use backspace as escape character such as Visual\ Basic.

How can I manage spaces in path in Visual Basic ? Is there a marker to enter before space to avoid the eror, or is there something else ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: The entire folder needs to be contained in quotes - `"C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WebApplication1"`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not seem to suffice. I use Command$ which contains the path of the dragged file. For instance as you said :

Comment: All good. I've definitely forgotten that before when switching between *nix and Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not seem to suffice. 

I use Command$ which contains the path of the dragged file. For instance as you said C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Text.txt. 

Then I try to open the said file with <snip>ReadAllText(Command$()) and that generates the error.

I tried <snip>ReadAllText(chr(34)+Command$()+chr(34)) but the error is still there. Any idea ?

Comment: Last minute : I copied the content of Command$ into a string and used that string. Problem gone. Did not come from spaces, but from the direct use of Command$ in a ReadAll. End bug :)

Comment: Last, last comment : I did not notice that Command$ contains a quote at the beginning and end. There are the illegal characters. I did a Replace and got rid of the critters. Now the bug is dead. It was not the spaces but the chr(34) :)

Answer (score 0):

Command() is an array of sting. When you pass the command line to your application it considers that spaces delimits new parameters unless you place them between double quotes.

Perhaps can you try with Command.ToString()